# Facebook Graph Api check if a loggedin user likes a post

Tags: facebook, user-interface, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I'm working on a app in which i need to check if the current logged In user liked a post from a particular page. So that i can show the appropriate like/liked button.
(I don't want to get all the likes of a post and iterate over them)

Alternatively i could use the FBSDKLikeControl, but my problem is i want to show custom like/liked buttons.

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
THE_POST_ID?fields=likes.summary(true).fields(name).limit(1)
```

And in the results check the "summary" dictionary you will get :

total_count,

can_like,

has_liked  <----this

(tested with graph api 2.5)

Comment: So is there no way to get other user has_liked my post by providing other user id ?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there is not a direct way using the GraphAPI to know if a user has liked an specific post or not besides going through all the post likes: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes